# Why does Spring Authorization Server use Base64StringKeyGenerator for generating tokens?

Tags: spring, spring-security, spring-authorization-server

I am currently working with Spring Authorization Server and noticed that it uses `Base64StringKeyGenerator` for generating tokens. However, I'm unsure about the reasoning behind this choice and whether it's expected for the generated tokens to appear as seemingly random strings without any useful information.

1. Why does Spring Authorization Server use `Base64StringKeyGenerator` for token generation? Are there specific advantages or considerations for this choice?
2. When inspecting the generated tokens, I noticed that they appear as random strings (e.g., `28VO6BUTCOPRTEmH5odQwuNSODE_T7e2nTvkiAZ0R3rTYwO0UmIE0_de9EeciUvDJFhpVtgd6KPIpavVhWJ7xTMSX2J1sIU8_ZfxaaH763S4DFHO8OFnmcygT8sLlBBQ`) without any discernible information. Is this behavior expected?
3. Should I expect the tokens generated by Spring Authorization Server to contain **meaningful information**, or is their purpose primarily for **secure identification and validation**?

Comment: Would you want tokens to be easily identifiable so that hackers could guess what the next or previous one was. Generate one and take over your system?

Comment: @M.Deinum Base64 encoding doesn't hide any information, so I don't believe it's to prevent hacking.  They're base64 encoded because the keys are a stream of bytes, and base64 encoding ensures that you can use them in URLs, headers, and other places where special characters are prohibited.  Base64 encoding also ensures that you can include encrypted, signed, content in the tokens that can be passed around without worrying about them being compromised.

Comment: I know how Base64 worked (wrote my own encoders/decoders when they weren't available in Java or libraries way back). The `Base64StringKeyGenerator` delegates to a `BytesKeyGenerator` which generates the actual key (which should be randomized). A token regardless of the use of base64 should be random and not guessable imho.

Comment: @M.Deinum I get that.  I just want to make sure the OP doesn't leave here thinking that base64 encoding somehow improves security.

Comment: thanks, why not use UUID? It's random and it's short , only 36 bits, ByteKeyGebnerator 
 default size is 96 bits. @M.Deinum

Comment: For example , in `Oauth2AccessTokenGenerator`, use UUID to generate `ClaimBuilder.id`. what's the difference?

Comment: @whywhathow `UUID` is intended for use in generating identifiers. Keys and tokens are not simply identifiers. They should be impervious to guessing and a host of other considerations, not just avoiding collision. I don't have references off-hand for this but I feel your question is too specific to SAS, and should be generalized to "keys vs IDs". I would guess there are already good answers on SO for that.